# Node.js Touchless (XCOPY) Install on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

This may be the wrong forum to ask this question, however is it possible to do a "touchless" node.js deployment?  For example, is it possible to push a copy of node.exe and the required packages to a physical location on the drive (assume the machine is generally in a disconnected state) then have a shortcut that executes the appropriate commandline to get the node process running?

I know that this is a loaded question, because without being physically installed on the box, and then running within a Windows Service, you lose all the lifetime management, and that is just scratching the surface of the things that need to be considered.  Anyway, I truly appreciate the help and opinions.

Comment: yeah, node.exe can run sibling js files "standalone" without being installed locally. at least, it would as of version 0.8x when i last tried...

Comment: You could as http://ninite.com/ to create an installer for node.js :p

Comment: Ask ninite.com on their feedback page: https://ninite.com/feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just coming back to clean up this answer.  Yes this is possible, but not always advisable.  Better to do an installation or leverage containers.